# Estimate Pi in SQL Monte Carlo Method

Tags: mysql, sql, pi

I'm trying to show the estimate of PI in SQL. I want my estimate to be numeric(12,11) but it only shows 4 digits total, with a precision of 3. How do I format this code?

---

```
declare @fNum as float
declare @yNum as float
declare @pi as float

declare @loopNum as int
declare @inCount as int = 0
declare @totalCount as int = 0
set @loopNum = 1000
declare @oDist as numeric

while @loopNum > 0

begin
set @totalCount +=1 
 set @fNum = rand () * 100 + 1
 set @yNum =  rand() * 100 +1 


    set @oDist = POWER(@fNum, 2.0) + Power(@yNum, 2.0) 

   if sqrt(@oDist)  <= 100.00
        set @inCount +=1

set @loopNum -= 1
set @pi = (4.0 *@inCount / @totalCount)

 end

select @inCount AS 'IN', @totalCount as 'ALL',/* @fNum as 'f', @yNum as     'y', sqrt(@oDist) as 'Origin'*/ cast(@pi as numeric(7,6)) as 'Pi'
 go
```

Comment: The output I want is 3.12896754312 but I get 3.12800000000.

Comment: Aside from this appearing to be a terrible approximation of PI, why do you want to do this in SQL in any case?

Comment: It's an assignment for school. Not my pick.

Comment: I would explain to the school that sql is not a panacea and is entirely inappropriate for such tasks.